# Quickly compare two database backup files

Tags: sql-server

In my work as a developer I often restore backups from a fileshare to my local sql server.

The latest backup is posted at irregular intervals on the fileshare. The new backup has the same name as the old one. I copy the backup file to my computer and restore it.

I would like to know if it is possible to quickly compare my local backup file to the one on the fileshare, do they have some embedded checksum or such?, so I know if it is worth to copy the file or not?

Comment: as beanfrog mentioned it is easily possible with MD5 comparison. you can either download the tool or make your own with for example c#. Question is though if you want to use a commandline tool, program a short program or JUST use sql server abilities to compare the backups (if only the later pls update your question to make it clear)

Comment: Well, the question is kind of open ended. The easiest might be to use something that is built in into sql server, but I'm willing to look at other options.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an MD5 to do this. It's a checksum for any file.

Microsoft have a utility for making these, and you can run it from the command line. Here's an article including a link to download:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841290

Comment: I tested this on my 800 mib backup file and it took 1-2 seconds locally, but when running from my local computer on the fileshare it took over a minute. It might be a solution to compute the md5 once and store it with the backup on the fileshare, but I was more looking for a quick way (seconds) to check the files without having to pre-generate something...

Comment: sounds like the problem is then the network connectivity to the shared files. that means then that a solution that works locally on that server where the share is located at is the only viable way.   is that the sql server server ?

Comment: No the location of the backup is not on the SQL server, it is just placed on a fileshare. The network is 100 mbit. I can see that my network card utilization is pretty much 100% for 1-2 minutes when copying the backup from the server. As I sometimes do a lot of restores when working on different branches I want to use a script to restore easily. I would like the script to always get the latest backup, but only copy the backup from the network when necessary.

Comment: what about modification date&time of the file? could that help there? as md5 and other solutions normally have to go through the whole file in order to look for differences they will then still read the whole file

Comment: Well, it might be an option. Problem is that CreationTime many times seems to be reset when copying files.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the creation date to compare sql backups. Since I use the comparison while doing development exact comparison of files are not necessary, and creating a MD5 just takes extra time.

The solution that I have use for my keeping my local sql development server up to date is using a script. I run this script once in a while to get a fresh database, or whenever I need a "clean" database backup.

The script will check for a new backup file. If a new file exist it will copy the new file to the local machine. After copy, the script will set the creation date  of the copied file will to the date of the source backup file. After the check and copy step the script will run a `RESTORE` command. The restore is run even if no new file is copied. After the restore the script calls RoundhousE (https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse) to execute any change scripts that I have in my GIT folder that have not been applied to the database. (RoundhousE has added tables that keep track of scripts that have been run, to the database).

That way I keep my sql development server up to date.